# MPChartAndroid: how to interact with a BarDataSet that has a missing Entry?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use the MPAndroidChart library to create a BarChart, in which some (future) values are not filled-in yet. So the chart contains information about a week,  you consult it on Thursday. (Mon, tue, wed, thu) are known and filled-in but (fri, sat, sun) are not. I'd like the app to respond on a click on any of the first four days, but not when any of the empty (fri, sat, sun) slots are clicked. I've been unable as yet to distinguish between these situations using the Entry, index and Highlight parameters of OnChartValueSelectedListener.onValueSelected. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer to my own question: when a BarDataSet is missing an entry, and you click on the empty space where the associated bar would have been, you can get its index through the XIndex property of the Highlight object parameter in an OnChartValueSelectedListener